# Memory issues when converting a pointer to std::uint64_t and back to a pointer again

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, casting, access-violation

The code is shown below.

```
struct tNode
{
    int data;
    tNode* next;
    tNode(const int& data, tNode* next = nullptr)
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = next;
    }
};

int main()
{
    tNode* ptr = new tNode(1);
    std::uint64_t num_ptr = reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t>(ptr);
    delete ptr;
    auto back_to_ptr = reinterpret_cast<tNode*>(num_ptr);
    tNode* ret = back_to_ptr->next;
    std::cout << ret;
}
```

When I tried debugging in Visual Studio 2022 using the MSVC compiler, I could not detect any errors.
I believe `tNode* ret = back_to_ptr->next;` should output error information about a memory access violation, so why is the above code working fine?

I've been searching for problems with converting pointers to int types.
Using Visual Studio 2022, I debugged the above example by taking breakpoints.

Comment: Well, it's undefined behaviour, so who knows what could happen.

Comment: `delete ptr;` tells the system, "I'm done with this and promise that I'll never look at it again. Feel free to release or reuse it when it's convenient to do so." A) You broke your promise! B) The system hasn't found it convenient to release or reuse the memory yet, so there's no error to be raised.

Comment: This has nothing to do with pointer conversions. You can just try `ptr->next;` directly. In either case, you are breaking the rules and any behaviour can result, including not crashing. But that behaviour is basically one random possible result, it could change at any time for no apparent reason. The mistake is to expect C++ to crash when you break the rules. Sometimes it works incorrectly, appears to work sometimes and other insidious results.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour.   Beginners (and even a few too many teachers) to C++ often believe "undefined behaviour" means "a crash or memory violation of some form".   When, in reality, undefined behaviour means "the C++ standard doesn't place any constraints on what happens".    So undefined behaviour can manifest in many ways.  One way is "seeming to work and passing all tests".  Another way is some form of memory related error.   A more insidious manifestation is "seems to work by passing all tests on the development computer but corrupts critical data on the customer's computer".

Comment: Side note: For now converting a pointer to a `uint64_t` is pretty safe. But it used to be pretty safe to convert a pointer to an `int`, so don't be surprised if stuffing a pointer in a `uint64_t` blows up in your face tomorrow. Prefer to use `uintptr_t`, an integer guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer.

Comment: `delete ptr;    auto back_to_ptr = reinterpret_cast<tNode*>(num_ptr);` No you can't use the back_to_ptr now it will point to already deleted memory. And this will lead to undefined behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here, fortunately, has nothing to do with the casting from integers to pointers or vice versa. Rather, the issue is that the line `delete ptr` does not do anything to `ptr` itself but instead destroys the object it points at. Any further use of that object, regardless of how you get a pointer to it, is classified as undefined behavior. That means that you *might* get a memory error, or you might not. In your case, it just so happens that you don’t get a crash or access violation even though what you’re doing clearly accesses an object after its lifetime ends.

Comment: And all of this is done (or rather NOT done) in the name of efficiency. This case is trivial and the Mark I eyeball picks it off quickly. In the general case checks to make sure the pointed-at object hasn't been released, necessary to report an error, would have to be made freaking everywhere, and that would add up to a serious performance hit. C++ has a policy of not making you pay for stuff you didn't expressly ask for, so in most cases NO checks are made and the compiler writes code under the assumption that you know what you're doing.